# Android Constraints - Buttons out of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, constraints, calculator, android-constraintlayout

I'm learning Android Development. I followed the google guide on developing a simple app if you already have programming experience. Now, I'm attempting to make a simple calculator. I seem to have some misunderstanding with constraints still. Below is how it looks in preview vs on my device (I can't simulate as my processor doesn't have the appropriate intrinsics).

Here's a pic:

[image]

I've tried watching some tutorials and reading online, what I've gotten is to have one constraint following another, parent<- child1 <- child2, etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button10"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.052" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button13"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.489"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button11"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.052" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button9"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.052" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/space" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/calcResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.54"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.489"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/calcResult" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button30"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/calcResult" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button31"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/space"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button30"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/calcResult" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button32"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button33"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/space"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/calcResult" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button33"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/calcResult" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/space" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/space" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As can be seen from the pic, the buttons are off the bottom of the screen. It also seems the spaces I design in the preview are different on the hardware. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I'm attempting to make a simple calculator. I seem to have some
>   misunderstanding with constraints still

Here, as for this layout, I overlooked and fixed it and hopefully according to your desire. And Reduced each button height to match with the resolution of the device screen.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button10"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button13"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button11"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.012" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button9"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.018" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/space" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button9"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button10"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/calcResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<Space
    android:id="@+id/space"
    android:layout_width="8dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/calcResult" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button30"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/calcResult" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button31"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/space"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button30"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/calcResult" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button32"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button33"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/space"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/calcResult" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button33"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/calcResult" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button8" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.507"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/space" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/space" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

***layout_marginStart*** and ***layout_marginLeft*** are same, so just use one of them.

Some design suggestions:

1. Try and fix all the yellow warnings, fixing all the warnings for layouts will have 40% of your work done as per designing. And 10% depends on the size and position of each items on the layout. Rest 50% is a bit hard but not that hard. For showing you a example for this, when designing is ready for the layout and having fixed all the warning, press the "Orientation For Preview" button to set the Landscape mode. You will see that everything is messed up. Fixing this will need to make a separate layout for the landscape view. Now, why am I saying about Landscape ? 
   Here comes the second part of the answer of your question:

> the buttons are off the bottom of the screen

2. Layout size is not same for all devices which you already know. So, when designing layouts, you have to keep track of the resolution of the screen. This is the reason the buttons are out off the screen. The resolution of the preview screen and the device screen are not same for your case. Try to select the preview resolution according to the device you are testing with by clicking the "Device For Preview" or 'Pixel' button of the layout preview.

Last but not the least, for both **better understanding the design criteria** along with **best practices of performance**,  complete all the 11 lessons from [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/) on "Developing Android Apps" course (free).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Very helpful :). I will definitely look at the course.

Comment: *Try to select the preview resolution according to the device you are testing*, look at my answer below explaining how you can make one layout to support all different kind of screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Please choose `relativeLayout` as your parent layout. In that use a `linearLayout` with vertical orientation. Inside this place your calculator screen(`EditText`) first with `center-horizontal` orientation. Then place a `center-horizontal` oriented `horizontalLinearLayout` and populate this with the top most row buttons. Next for the numeric keypad, use a table layout with `center` orientation. You can then easily populate this table layout with your buttons.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I'm a bit confused. "Inside place calculator screen first with center-horizontal orientation"?

Comment: Inside the vertical linear layout, place an edit text with center horizontal orientation

Answer (score 0):

**Different phones got different screen size**, in your layout you are using fixed size on your view (fixed size is `50dp` for example) and the result is that what may look good on one screen (your android studio preview screen) will not look good on another screen (your actual phone).

You can use Use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) with [guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) and [Chains](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html) to support different screen sizes.

**Here is an example of a similar layout using ConstraintLayout without any fixed size values (one layout for all screen sizes):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button13"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button9"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button16"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button10"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button8"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button14"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button11"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button15"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button12"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button7" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button10"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button11"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button9" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button12"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button7"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button8"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button11" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button16"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button14"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button15"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button16" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button15"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button8"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button14" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button16"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button14"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button13" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".3" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**And it will look like this:**

[image]